# SQL Server supports a maximum sector size of 4096 bytes

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012. It fails with message

> Cannot use file 'D:\SQL\tempdb.mdf', because it is on a volume with
>   sector size 8192. SQL Server supports a maximum sector size of 4096
>   bytes. Move the file to a volume with a compatible sector size.

But `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo d:` shows:

```
NTFS Volume Serial Number:       0x281643d216439fa4
NTFS Version:                    3.1
LFS Version:                     2.0
Number Sectors:                  0x00000000e8d29fff
Total Clusters:                  0x000000003a34a7ff
Free Clusters:                   0x000000002a37c684
Total Reserved:                  0x0000000000000000
Bytes Per Sector:                1024
Bytes Per Physical Sector:       4096
Bytes Per Cluster:               4096
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment:    1024
Clusters Per FileRecord Segment: 0
Mft Valid Data Length:           0x000000000a540000
Mft Start Lcn:                   0x00000000000c0000
Mft2 Start Lcn:                  0x0000000000000002
Mft Zone Start:                  0x00000000000ca540
Mft Zone End:                    0x00000000000cc820
RM Identifier:                   F3BAAB08-F2E7-11E2-804B-3C4A9279C348
```

D: drive is RAID 0 drive with total capacity of 4 TB made from two 2 TB disks. RAID controller is AMD RAID and its utility shows that disk's sector size is 1 KB:
[image: RAID utility screenshot]

Why SQL Server setup program thinks that disk sector size is 8K and what needs to be done to install SQL Server on this disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That AMD RAID is almost definitely software RAID and is probably reporting weird things to the OS.

Use striping at the OS level and see if that fixes your problem.

Just [be aware that if one drive fails you'll lose all data on your 4TB volume](https://serverfault.com/q/339128).

I really really hope you're ONLY using this for development.

Comment: Looks like you are right and problem was causing by AMD RAID driver. I've tried to replace default Windows Server 2012 driver with latest driver from AMD (3.8.1540.30). That didn't help. Then I've tried older driver (3.2.1540.75), just in case. I was using it for Windows Server 2008 R2 before upgrading to 2012. With this driver the problem disappeared.

Comment: And yes, I am using this RAID array as a storage for nonsensitive data, so data loss won't be a big problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what it's really complaining about is the NTFS Cluster Size, which was set at format-time. The [default size for a 4TB volume](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140365) is a 4KB cluster, so I'm not sure how it would get set to 8KB unless it was set by hand. `chkdsk` will show your cluster size.

Comment: Yes I thought about that, but I remember I left cluster size option in default state (which was 4K) at format time. `chkdsk` also reported that cluster size is 4K. Looks like it is a bug in latest version of AMD RAID driver.